# dc.js / d3.js - How to hide a bar chart x-axis category value if its bar value equals zero for stacked groups?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts, dc.js

I am working on a dashboard. I want the bar charts to update such that the x-axis categories are removed from the graph when they are zero and will reappear when they are not.  In other words, when a bar chart is updated, it should only show the bars with values greater than 0.  The graphs are updated when selecting/unselecting elements in other graphs.

It is working for when there is only 1 group.  It does not work when the second bar graph has stacked groups.  The error is occurring in d3.v3.js on line 6670.  I am getting the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Is there an example somewhere that shows how to do this? I have not been able to find one.

This is the code that isn't working:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var bar1 = dc.barChart("#bar1");
var bar1_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.name;});
var bar1_group = bar1_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.count;});
var bar1_Fgroup = remove_empty_bins(bar1_group);
bar1.width(650).height(310)
    .dimension(bar1_dim)
    .group(bar1_Fgroup)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .gap(2)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .yAxisLabel("count")
    .margins({top:10,left:60,right:10,bottom:110});

bar1.on("renderlet",function(_chart){
    _chart.selectAll("g.x text").style("text-anchor","end")
          .attr('dx', '-15').attr('dy', '-2').attr('transform', "rotate(-75)");
    _chart.selectAll("rect.bar").on("click", _chart.onClick);
});

var bar2 = dc.barChart("#bar2");
var bar2_dim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.name;});
var bar2_group1 = bar2_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {if (d.FiscYr == "2011"){return +d.count;}else{return 0;});
var bar2_group2 = bar2_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {if (d.FiscYr == "2012"){return +d.count;}else{return 0;});
var bar2_group3 = bar2_dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {if (d.FiscYr == "2013"){return +d.count;}else{return 0;});
var bar2_Fgroup1 = remove_empty_bins(bar2_group1);
var bar2_Fgroup2 = remove_empty_bins(bar2_group2);
var bar2_Fgroup3 = remove_empty_bins(bar2_group3);
bar.width(650).height(310)
    .dimension(bar2_dim)
    .group(bar2_Fgroup1)
    .stack(bar2_Fgroup2)
    .stack(bar2_Fgroup3)
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .gap(2)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .elasticY(true)
    .elasticX(true)
    .yAxisLabel("count")
    .margins({top:10,left:60,right:10,bottom:110});

bar2.on("renderlet",function(_chart){
    _chart.selectAll("g.x text").style("text-anchor","end")
          .attr('dx', '-15').attr('dy', '-2').attr('transform', "rotate(-75)");
    _chart.selectAll("rect.bar").on("click", _chart.onClick);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting separately and not confusing the old question. Now that I see this, it reminds me of an earlier question. Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886088/dc-js-stacked-bar-chart-with-empty-bin-filter-displaying-in-strange-way/30899172#30899172

Comment: I noticed that none of the codes in the jsfiddles from that link provide a working example.  When "B" is clicked on, the "B" values are not updated correctly -- nor are they for "A".  Has the solution been corrupted?  I haven't tried their solution yet.  I'm about to test it out.

Comment: I just tried their solution, and it worked.  Thank you!