# dc.js Ordering X-Axis by Month

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter, stacked-chart

I am trying to create a Stacked Bar Chart using dc.js as following:

Data:

```
<pre id="data">
Status,StatusT,Phase,PhaseT,CompletionDate,CalMonth,Sales,SalesCount
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20130101,201012,2203262.13,1
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20130101,201111,607933.8,1
3,Won,Z05,Deliver,20131001,201202,66.08,1
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20120501,201202,66.08,1
3,Won,Z01,Understand,20120409,201203,65.07,1
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20121231,201204,4645214.7,1
3,Won,Z05,Deliver,20130918,201204,66.52,1
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20130418,201204,2312130.92,1
3,Won,Z05,Deliver,20120504,201205,68.07,1
3,Won,Z05,Deliver,20120504,201205,515994.86,1
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20120504,201205,68.07,1
3,Won,Z04,Decide,20120504,201205,68.07,1
</pre>
```

Javascript:

```
var dateFormat = d3.time.format('%Y%m%d');
var monthNameFormat = d3.time.format("%b-%Y");
// Prepare Data
for (var z = 0; z < opportunities.length; z++) {
  opportunities[z].DD = dateFormat.parse(opportunities[z].CompletionDate);
}

opportunities.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.DD - a.DD;
});

var ndx = crossfilter(opportunities);

var dimMonthYear = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  //return d.CompletionDate
  return monthNameFormat(new Date(d.DD));
});

var phaseUnderstand = dimMonthYear.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  if (d.Phase === "Z01") {
    return d.Sales;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
var phasePropose = dimMonthYear.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  if (d.Phase === "Z02") {
    return d.Sales;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
var phaseNegotiate = dimMonthYear.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  if (d.Phase === "Z03") {
    return d.Sales;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
var phaseDecide = dimMonthYear.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  if (d.Phase === "Z04") {
    return d.Sales;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
var phaseDeliver = dimMonthYear.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  if (d.Phase === "Z05") {
    return d.Sales;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});

chart
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .margins({
    left: 80,
    top: 20,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 80
  })
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .round(d3.time.month.round)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .brushOn(false)
  .xAxisLabel('Months')
  .yAxisLabel("Expected Sales (in thousands)")
  .dimension(dimMonthYear)
  .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
 // .barPadding(0.1)
  //.outerPadding(0.05)
  .legend(dc.legend().x(130).y(30).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
  .group(phaseUnderstand, "Understand")
  .stack(phasePropose, "Propose")
  .stack(phaseNegotiate, "Negotiate")
  .stack(phaseDecide, "Decide")
  .stack(phaseDeliver, "Deliver")
  .centerBar(true)
  .elasticY(true)
  .elasticX(true)
  .renderlet(function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll("g.x text").attr('dx', '-30').attr(
      'dy', '-7').attr('transform', "rotate(-60)");
  });
chart.render();
```

I am able to render the chart but I am not able to sort the X-axis by month in ascending order and make it elastic along the x-axis. If I use just date then the chart becomes too detailed (although x-axis is still not elastic) which is not useful for the purpose I am creating it for. Here is a sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NewMonk/1hbjwxzy/67/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend using time scales when the X axis is time-based. It's just a little more work (and more risk of the dreaded Blank Chart), but it's way more flexible and accurate.

First off, we need to ask crossfilter to bin by month. `d3.time.month` will round each date down to the nearest month:

```
var dimMonthYear = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return d3.time.month(d.DD)
});
```

This has the same effect as the string-bins you were creating, but it keeps the keys as dates.

Then we can tell dc.js to use a time-based scale and elasticX:

```
chart
  .x(d3.time.scale()).elasticX(true)
  .round(d3.time.month.round)
  .alwaysUseRounding(true)
  .xUnits(d3.time.months)
```

`.xUnits` is what gets the bar width right (so that dc.js can count the number of visible bars).

We can restore the `monthNameFormat` tick format and show every tick like so:

```
chart.xAxis()
  .tickFormat(monthNameFormat)
  .ticks(d3.time.months,1);
```

Finally, you may need to [remove empty bins](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#remove-empty-bins) if filtering with another chart, so that bars will be removed when they drop to zero:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                return d.value != 0;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

#### Afterword

@Kush comments below that removing the empty bins from a stacked set of date-based groups is not easy. It is so.

Here's a custom version of [combine_groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#combine-groups) for combining date-based groups:

```
function combine_date_groups() { // (groups...)
    var groups = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return {
        all: function() {
            var alls = groups.map(function(g) { return g.all(); });
            var gm = {};
            alls.forEach(function(a, i) {
                a.forEach(function(b) {
                    var t = b.key.getTime();
                    if(!gm[t]) {
                        gm[t] = new Array(groups.length);
                        for(var j=0; j<groups.length; ++j)
                            gm[t][j] = 0;
                    }
                    gm[t][i] = b.value;
                });
            });
            var ret = [];
            for(var k in gm)
                ret.push({key: new Date(+k), value: gm[k]});
            return ret;
        }
    };
}
```

The nasty thing here is that we have to convert from dates to integers in order to index the objects correctly, and then convert the integers back to dates when building the fake group data.

Apply it like this:

```
var combinedGroup = combine_date_groups(remove_empty_bins(phaseUnderstand), 
    remove_empty_bins(phasePropose), 
    remove_empty_bins(phaseNegotiate), 
    remove_empty_bins(phaseDecide), 
    remove_empty_bins(phaseDeliver));
```

Here's a helper function for pulling a stack by index:

```
function sel_stack(i) {
    return function(d) {
    return d.value[i];
  };
}
```

Now we can specify the stacks like this:

```
chart
  .group(combinedGroup, "Understand", sel_stack(0))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Propose", sel_stack(1))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Negotiate", sel_stack(2))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Decide", sel_stack(3))
  .stack(combinedGroup, "Deliver", sel_stack(4))
```

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/8pc0p1we/17/

(Forgot to post the fiddle the first time, I think it was at about version 8 before this adventure.)

We're so far beyond what crossfilter and dc.js were originally designed for, it's kind of humorous. Data is complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. It worked like a charm but now I am stuck with removing empty bins and combining all the groups as you suggested for filtering with another chart. Do I really need to combine all the groups ? Is there an example which I can refer to ? I followed [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886088/dc-js-stacked-bar-chart-with-empty-bin-filter-displaying-in-strange-way). But sadly it has resulted into a blank white chart. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh boy. Good point, that's not easy stuff at all. I've updated my answer above. We really need a data preprocessing library to sit between crossfilter and dc.js.

Comment: Needless to say, combining the groups now works. However still no elasticity in the x-axis ([this is my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NewMonk/8pc0p1we/18/)). Is there something which I am still doing wrong or missing out ?

Comment: Ugh I didn't have anything to test against, so I forgot to actually `remove_empty_bins(...)` on everything. Corrected above.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you but I couldn't still make it to work. It seems that this is being caused by negative/floating point values. For example consider this sample bin:
`code
key: Mon Oct 01 2012 00:00:00
0:0
1:0
2:0
3:-9.313225746154785e-10
4:0
`


[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NewMonk/8pc0p1we/20/)

Comment: and then I remembered reading [about snap to zero](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#snap-to-zero) somewhere. I wrapped my groups in this function and IT WORKED :-)
`code
var combinedGroup = combine_date_groups(remove_empty_bins(snap_to_zero(phaseUnderstand)),
  remove_empty_bins(snap_to_zero(phasePropose)),
  remove_empty_bins(snap_to_zero(phaseNegotiate)),
  remove_empty_bins(snap_to_zero(phaseDecide)),
  remove_empty_bins(snap_to_zero(phaseDeliver)));`

Comment: Oh my goodness. That's a real mess but it makes sense. Glad you got it working!